# inverse futures hedging

Tags: futures, bitcoin

This is my first question here and I hope I don't make any mistakes.

I have kind of a problem with spreading and hedging inverse futures such as Bitmex 3m or 6m XBTUSD contracts due to their non - linearity.

They have sensitivity towards interest rates and the spot market, but no matter how I twist and turn it, I cannot figure out how to create a spread (e.g. 3m-6m) that is neutral to even one of these variables.

A dollar neutral spread acts like a risk reversal, a BTC neutral spread is not neutral to DV01, an interest rate neutral hedge ration is all over the place when it comes to spot sensitivity...

I just think I don'T understand these things at all...where do I start to look?

Comment: To be honest this is not clear to me what you are trying to do or what is the issue.

Comment: ok, so this might end up in a wall of text that hopefully makes sense.

Comment: When it comes to trading the yield curve via interest rate futures, their properties are well known (DV01, convexity, etc. books have been written...)

With these things I just don't know the angle I have to attack the hedging problem from. Lets say you want to buy the 3m and sell the 6m against it. BTC rises, forward curve steepens so the trade is losing. But since your P/L is settled in BTC, your loss in USD is bigger, too. So this is convexity I don't know how to hedge against, since I don't know my loss in advance

Comment: Now imagine a butterfly. I think the 3m premium of 10% apr is too large compared to the 7% apr of the weekly and 8% apr of the 6m. How do I normalise this trade for term and isolate the interest rate component?

Each contract has a different sensitivity for interest rates which is not tied to it's premium delta in a linear fashion. In other words when BTC crashes, the 6m loses more absolute premium (lets say 1.25 times the premium of the 3m) but as soon as I adjust the hedging ratio to 1.25 x 3m for each 6m I'm not neutral towards interest rates anymore since the 6m is 1.8 times...

Comment: ...as sentisitve towards interest rates compared to the 3 month.
So every time I try to tie down one end, I open another can of worms.

Comment: I'd be very happy if someone pointed me into the right direction I have to research. Inverse futures are kind of a novum, but perhaps there is an exotic equivalent where there has been discussions about pricing. 
Thanks for reading.